# Error: number of observations <= number of random effects for LMER

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lme4

I have the following code:

```
model <- lmer(Scores ~ Group*Time + (Time | ID), positiveaffect)
```

I am trying to run a linear mixed effects model with Group as a **between-subjects** variable and Time as a **within-subjects variable**, taking into account the **interaction** between Group and Time.

Each participant has two measurements (one from each time point: time point 1 and 2).

However, I get this error when I run the code:

```
Error: number of observations (=89) <= number of random effects (=90) for term (Time | ID); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable
```

I am not sure what I need to do to overcome this?

I would be so grateful for your help!

Minimal reproducible example:

```
structure(list(Group = c("SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "HC", 
"HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", 
"HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", 
"HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC"), Time = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2), Scores = c(16, 18, 24, 31, 11, 14, 23, 17, 19, 10, 
16, 22, 19, 19, 23, 20, 14, 17, 29, 20, 16, 30, 26, 18, 21, 20, 
19, 15, 39, 11, 15, 28, 35, 16, 10, 15, 17, 21, 23, 12, 17, 22, 
13, 17, 13, 17, 18, 19, 17, 16, 24, 20, 22, 19, 18, 24, 13, 24, 
28, 24, 26, 13, 28, 10, 24, 32, 34, 36, 16, 25, 28, 30, 27, 24, 
19, 19, 20, 20, 10, 22, 15, 12, 20, 26, 17, 21, 24, 27, 31, 16
), ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I see it correctly, you just have one observation per id.
You would at least need a lower number of levels of each grouping factor than the number of observations. Here the number of observations is 89 and you have 89 different groups, as you have one group by id and only one observation by id.

Comment: I have re-organised my dataset but I'm still getting the same error! (edited above)

Comment: You still have not enough variation. So if you think about fixed effects capturing all the variation across time and id in your case, you cannot estimate a main effect for group, because some ids are in group 1 and some in group2, but none in both (I understand the setting, so that is what it is). However, having fixed effect for id already explain this variation, as there is no id which is in both groups, there is no additional variation that ca be explain due to the main effect.

Comment: When I try this: model <- lmer(Scores ~ Time + (Time | ID), positiveaffect), I still get the same error! What should I change?

Comment: What approach can I try/how should I change my code to get the output I want?

Comment: You could use the group instead of the id fixed effect: model <- lmer(Scores ~ Group*Time + (Time | Group), data=d)

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried that and it worked :))